# How to supply event coordinates for real-time insights events?

Tags: real-time, ibm-cloud, iot

When we look at the IoT Real-Time Insights service, we see that it provides a visual mapping capability.  Unfortunately, the current documentation on using this appears to be very light.  What should the JSON string structure of an incoming event contain to provide latitude and longitude data to the Map widget within a Real-Time Insights dashboard?

References:

- Documentation consulted looking for mapping parameters: http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/iotrtinsights/dashboards.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the creation of an IBM IoT Real-Time Insights environment, one must build the schema that describes the content of an incoming event.  Within an event, we get to specify "data points" which are basically the fields within the incoming event.  When we define a data point there is an attribute of it called "Sensor type" which is presumably used to provide a "hint" as to what kind of sensor produced that field in the event.  Contained within this set are two pre-defined values called `Longitude` and `Latitude` and these provide the core of the answer.  When we define the schema of an incoming event and we know that two arbitrarily named fields that we have chosen will contain the latitude and longitude information for a geospatial position, we need to define them as having the sensor types appropriate for their purpose.  Here is an example screen shot illustrating a definition:

[image]

Notice specifically the value of "Sensor type".

Answer (score 0):

The JSON structure is not really important as long as the message includes two data points, one representing lat and one long. By configuring these data points with the data type Float and the sensor types `Latitude` and `Longitude` in the Message Schema you enable the Map widget to use these as latitude and longitude coordinates.

Sample IoT Phone JSON structure that includes lat and long data points:

```
{"d":
{"id":"Name","ts":1455715675212,"lat":33.889868355549225,"lng":-77.99657438767082,"ax":-0.04,"ay":-0.03,"az":0.09,"oa":24.28,"ob":11.84,"og":1.97}
}
```